# Oracle dead with unknown reason

Tags: oracle

Our oracle database dead from time to time.When i look into the log in the alert.It shows:

> Exception [type: SIGSEGV, Address not mapped to object] [ADDR:0xFFFFFFFEAA7DD0E0] [PC:0x8213123, kslgetl()+111] [flags: 0x0, count: 1]
>
> ORA-07445: [kslgetl()+111] [SIGSEGV] [ADDR:0xFFFFFFFEAA7C58C0] [PC:0x8213123] [Address not mapped to object] []
>
> DDE: Problem Key 'ORA 7445 [kslgetl()+111]' was completely flood controlled (0x6)
>
> Further messages for this problem key will be suppressed for up to 10 minutes
>
> Errors in file /home/oracle/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/orcl/SDH/trace/SDH_p104_2581.trc  (incident=82376):
>
> ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [ksl_invalid_latch], [kslges], [0x2AFF2F2D8], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []

Database version is Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Any idea? thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason that you haven't applied any patchsets to your database?  You're running the very first 11.2 release.  Do you have a support contract?  ORA-00600 and ORA-00745 errors are internal Oracle errors.  Normally, you'd use the Metalink search tools to see whether the ORA-00600 and ORA-00745 error lookup tools find anything useful or whether you need to log a support request.

Answer (score 2):

http://support.oracle.com

There are at least 3 notes about these errors.

"The issue has been fixed in 11.1.0.7 and 11.2."

Comment: our database version is Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production.should fix this problem?

Comment: you need to log this with Oracle Support